# Error when deleting rows from a database

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, msdn

I am using this code to attempt to delete data from my table:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete * from login", con);
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When I run this I receive this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '*'

Answer (score 3):

The standard syntax for a DELETE statement is

```
 DELETE from <tablename> WHERE <condition>
```

No asterisk is needed before FROM. Just MS-Access likes that syntax.

Also keep in mind that if you don't add a WHERE condition, the whole table is deleted but this could be easier and faster with

```
 DROP TABLE <tablename>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from login", con);
```

You don't have to specify which column you are deleting, as you always delete entire rows. That's why you don't have to write *

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your query.

Instead of writing:

```
Delete * from login
```

You should write:

```
Delete from login
```

Exp: in `delete` command we don't need to write `*` as in a `select` statement since you cannot delete only certain columns but the entire row. The `where` clause can still be applied, however, to select specific rows.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot David.I will take care of these mistakes in future.

Answer (score 0):

Remove * and your query is as good as you are.